# Is my proposed neural implant feasible?

Tags: science-based, near-future, trans-humanism, neuroscience

In my story a computer-brain interface called T-ANGI is as widespread as smartphones are today.

They allow users to "outsource" computation intensive tasks and memory retrieval to data centers, help with pattern recognition and connect to the internet. Most important to the plot, they can act as perception filters (at least for sight and hearing). I can remove, change or add capabilities to keep it minimally invasive but the perception filter and pattern recognition needs to stay.

The T-ANGI (Thalamic ANgiocatheter Guided Implant) goes under the skin at the back of the neck and the electrode connected to the thalamus (although that part may change if needed) travels through the blood vessels (like pacemakers today) as to make it minimally invasive.

EDIT: the perception filter is used to interface wirelessly with sensory augmentations like night vision, extended auditory frequencies or even other stuff such as beaming footage or audio straight to the brain from an external device or for advanced sex toys (that way they don't need any extra surgeries for them) and also to block certain stuff (pain or traumatic stuff comes to mind although that may change). What kicks the plot in motion is when the company that makes the implant tries to implement a copyright filter like what social networks use to remove copyrighted material from perception if accessed illegally (this cause a disgruntled former employee to start hunting down people involved in the project before it can get implemented. Yes, it'll get somewhat dystopian)

**Would this work and be possible a world like ours in the early 2030s?**

Comment: If it can interact with our memories it needs to be very invasive, memory is stored all over the brain. Ditto for interfering with senses, since the senses enter the brain in different places, smell for instance bypasses the thalamus entirely.

Comment: The blood vessels under the skin at the back of the neck do not go anywhere near the brain. (And having a wire travel through the delicate blood vessels of the brain is very very much more invasive than having it travel trough regular tissue. Pacemaker leads travel through big strong veins.)

Comment: They would only "index" memories (like to avoid "tip of the tongue" or "where have I seen this guy?" Issues) although I can scrap that if needed as it's not really important

Comment: Could you add a sentence or two explaining what the perception filter is doing?

Comment: @ooak if you pop ***augmented reality glasses*** into any search engine I am very sure you'll find plenty of descriptions of what he's talking about there, he's just used less common phrasing for it.

Comment: @pelinore True, but I think it's better to spell out what is meant then relying on a vague meaning. The edit does this nicely.

Comment: @Pelinore yes. It's AR but straight to the brain instead of relying on our sensory organs. You can also use it as an interface for external devices (maybe the spies can broadcast drone or satellite footage to their visual cortex, or instantaneous translation with comm badges beaming straight to language centers)

Comment: First, it is completely unreasonable to expect it in  2030. That is absolutely a non-starter. Secondly, the bandwidth of a single electrode just is not capable of transmitting the volume of information necessary in anywhere near a timely fashion. However, a hair net of electrodes covering the entire scalp, maybe a thousand or so points of contact over the entire skull, you might just be somewhere close to barely plausible. However, it would have to be interfaced to a huge computer network, like Alexia.

Comment: But it sounds like it is a McGuffin, and readers do not generally take McGuffins as a serious hindrance if the writing is good enough.

Comment: it´s kind of a McGuffin since i just really need a way to implement the copyright filter and kick the plot into motion but i tried to make it something people may genuinely want despite the obvious risks (again, like smatphones) instead of opening the can of worms of having a totalitarian governmennt mandate it. Maybe that´s a better question to ask

Comment: huge computer networks are not an issue. we already have those and as long as we can connect to the internet is ok. Tech megacorps rutinely use them to run their services

Comment: Perhaps a subdermal encephalography (over the skull under the skin) to cut down on the amount of wire in the actual brain, chuck in a Bluetooth implant for internet cloud connection and you've got the output, add a reverse Neuralink for your input and Bob's your uncle, Bob is a monkey who likes playing pong, he already has Neuralink, you may have seen his YouTube video  @JustinThymetheSecond is right about 2030 being *a **bit** ambitious* in the real world though, but this ain't the real world of course 

Comment: You might be interested in this. "Cortex-wide neural interfacing via transparent polymer skulls"  https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-09488-0

Comment: @Pelinore add that as an anawer so i can accept it!

Comment: Don't forget about Elon Musk. https://www.inverse.com/article/31610-elon-musk-neural-link ELON MUSK'S NEURAL LACE COULD BE AN INJECTABLE THINKING CAP

Comment: It might also be worth looking at David Langford's [Different Kinds of Darkness](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/different-kinds-of-darkness/) as an example of fiction where the technology just _exists_, and no attempt is made to explain it.

Comment: Logically, sensory filters ought to be possible if you intercept the signal en route to the brain. Bear in mind that the optical nerve is so integrated with the brain that some consider the eyes as almost an extension of the brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have the `science-based` tag on this question, the answer is "We don't know."

Doing this would require learning a huge amount about the functioning of the brain. A full understanding of the way we form mental models of the world would seem necessary for the perception filter. A comprehensive insight into the basis of memory storage and retrieval is necessary for "outsourced" memory, and an understanding of thought formation seems required for outsourced processing. It is possible that we will learn these things in the next decade, but it would require at least one transforming insight, and those cannot be predicted. We have been trying to understand the operation of brains for centuries, and have not got very far.

Even given the required breakthroughs, I think it might take decades for this technology to become widely popular. Fitting it involves surgery, and it has deep and complex interaction with your brain. *We can't fix damaged brains.* If it "grows" into place, malfunctions at that stage are likely to be fatal. Until the process becomes extremely reliable, few people are likely to adopt it.

Comment: Thanks! I already improved my question here:

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/235141/ubiquitous-perception-in-2030s

Comment: *"A full understanding of the way we form mental models of the world would seem necessary"* Yeah, the main reason I hesitated to try an answer myself, would require some pretty extensive neural mapping both for the 'input' and 'output', there's been some promising work on that (a certain area lights up when you think the word 'fire' (air force weapons control research) and the monkey pong video where they've mapped the motor control sections used for joystick control) .. [continued]

Comment: [continued] .. but aside from being a fraction of what's needed and taking a lot of time just for those little bits I'm not really sure that person to person the same 'maps' apply, if you have to do it for every individual it may not be reasonably 'cost effective?' (for want of better words I'm sure I'll think of later ) .. the alternative approach is to rely at least partially on brain plasticity, you drop the wires and chips in and just let the person 'learn' to use them, that likely will work better (if it works) the younger the recipient is.

Comment: The critical path has several huge obstacles, but probably the biggest one is that science still knows very little about the relationship between the brain and the mind. One of the few things we do know is that the brain does _not_ work like a computer. This problem did not stop The Matrix from making a bajillion dollars. Nobody stormed out of the movie theater shouting "that's not how brains work!"